# jQuery css toggle - need to add fade in fade out animation transition

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate, toggle

I would like to add an animation transition to this snippet which I am using to toggle between a display: none and display: block

```
    jQuery(".slide").hover(
function() {
    jQuery(this).find(".data").css("display","block");
},
function() {
    jQuery(this).find(".data").css("display","none");
    }
    );
```

Any help is greatly appreciated...my jQuery is very limited. I have tried various items but can't seem to get good syntax to produce the effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use .hide() and .show()

```
  jQuery(".slide").hover(
function() {
    jQuery(this).find(".data").show("slow", "swing")
},
function() {
    jQuery(this).find(".data").hide("slow", "swing")
    }
    );
```

This is from the jquery website:

```
$(selector).hide(speed,easing,callback)
```

- speed can be slow, fast or the miliseconds
- easing can be swing or linear
- callback can be used to call a function

See [here](http://api.jquery.com/hide/)

I would always use show and hide over css display.

EDIT:

You can also try .slideUp(), which hides the element with a sliding motion. See [here](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/)

```
  jQuery(".slide").hover(
function() {
    jQuery(this).find(".data").slideDown("slow", "swing")
},
function() {
    jQuery(this).find(".data").slideUp("slow", "swing")
    }
    );
```

Comment: Thanks, that works and looks awesome. How can I do something like a slide up and down up effect instead of swing.

Comment: No problem. Try linear instead of swing. Another option could be to use .slideUp(). See my edited post for this. I may have got slideup and slidedown the wrong way around.

Comment: On a side note, I do appreciate the references to the jQuery site. I wish it was a little more "learner-friendly" and not so esoteric. As many hours as I have spent reading there looking for solutions, I have never once been able to decipher that site enough to actually find a solution. It would be nice with beginners if they dumbed it down a bit LOL.

Comment: Actually, I do know what you mean. I referenced them because they are the "offical" guide, but I actually learn alot more from w3schools. http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_hide_show.asp

Answer (score 1):

You can use `fadeToggle` method.

```
$(".slide").hover(function() {
    $(this).find(".data").fadeToggle();
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I like this method too!